# How can I automate the installation of an Ubuntu image using a USB device?

Tags: linux, ssh, ethernet, disk-image, dd

I have to automate the installation of a Linux image. The perfect behavior would be that I plug the USB, turn on the device and it runs the `dd` command in order to flash the image stored in the USB into the device. Also the ethernet port could be used

What I think maybe could be done is to launch a script from the USB that changes the configuration of the device and copies a .sh file, reboots it and uses that .sh file at the beginning to, using the dd command, flashes the image that is stored in the USB into the device.

Comment: What is the target device?

Comment: The target device is a tablet with ubuntu installed.What I would like to do is to install on a lot of those tablets the same image previously created. Thanks for the info!